# Remove Backup Drive, Windows 7 Fails to Boot?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bios, sata

I have 3 drives, 1 SSD (Letter E primary OS) and 2 backup SATA drives (C and D). In BIOS when I disable either or both of the SATA drives, the computer will fail to start. From what I have read, it sounds like the boot files are on one of the SATA drives, but looking at disk management I don't see a 100mb partition on any of them.

The C drive has an older installation of Windows 7 on it, but D drive has nothing but backup files (and this drive is dying from bad sectors) why I don't understand this.

How can I make the SSD (E) primary and safely disable the other disks?

[image]

Comment: None; Of your disk have the 100MB; doesn't mean the boot partition isn't on of them.   D is clearly marked as the system disk though.  **Your boot manager likely is on C.**  Just repair the boot manger when both devies are disconnected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a partition directly from Windows installation disk, then you have a 100 MB boot drive, then you can't change your primary drive, even you can't clone your windows.

windows disk manager doesn't show small partition, you should use a external bootable software like Acronis Disk Director if you want to see all partitions and Disks.

and if you haven't the 100 MB partition (you have a "boot" folder in Windows partition instead) you can migrate your OS to any disk or partition by some bootable software like Acronis True Image, and mark it as Active, then you can disable or remove the other Disks.

By the way, you shouldn't disable anything in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and used a Windows CD and the recovery console was able to correct the startup errors, placing the system partition on the SSD. I thought I could simply turn drives off from BIOS by disabling them in the boot order but seems that is not the case.